# Is there a halachik problem with wearing shorts while davening?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, clothing, tznius-modesty

I have often heard that one should not wear shorts while davening. This makes intuitive sense to me that we should do this out of respect.  But is there any halachic reasoning behind this? Is it absolutely forbidden to wear shorts while davening, or is this just something that is nice to do?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2463

Comment: You should probably [edit] in to the question whether you're asking about men only, women only, or anyone.

Comment: if a king/president/high official or some sort was standing in front of you, would you be wearing shorts or not?

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaAgob nope. I agree that the idea is logical. The question is whether it is halakha.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaAgob Is the president wearing shorts?

Comment: @doubleaa  Only on vacation/playing golf.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaAgob Well if he was, then I would be too.

Comment: @daniel my holocho says its not permitted

Comment: @doubleaa he doesn't meet others with shorts on business or other meetings. Maybe just on vacations with others of his league. If he wore shorts then according to contemporary holocho it would be fine, however even then I wouldn't because dress codes have changed for the worse. And if a king is wearing something, doesn't mean one should wear it infront of HaShem.

Comment: Applying this "would you meet the head of state in these clothes" standard is difficult as a practical matter.  If I were meeting the President, I would wear a suit.  Must I wear a suit every single day of my life?
I have been to synagogues which will not allow people wearing shorts to lead the davening, but don't throw them out of shul.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen Moreover, I'd probably shave and shower before going to meet him. Must I do that 3 times a day??

Comment: @doubleAA Moreover, even those who wear a hat/jacket for davening will wear a weekday one, which they won't wear to a wedding, kal vachomer greet a king.

Comment: IIRC Hacham Ovadia Shalit"a holds that in a place where it is accepted to wear shorts during Tefila it would be permitted.

Comment: I read in Sefer BeYishak Yekare on Mishna Berura Siman 2 that it is not proper to wear shorts Bichlal-according to Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (but I don't think it is talking MeIkar HaDin).

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen: If you meet up with the President every day, three times a day, then do you still really have to wear a suit every single time? Or can you you wear something more comfortable?

Comment: @unforgettableid Based on the "West Wing", even people who see the president every day put on their suit jackets to see him. So, no the standard doesn't decline in that way.

Comment: Is there a reason you left this question gender-ambiguous?

Comment: Some consider it non-tznius all the time (even for men)

Answer (score 1):

My Rabbi pointed out to me a prohibition on wearing shorts in synagogue, in a book on halacha.

I don't recall if it mentioned the following, which I've heard. In the case of kibbutzim, where anyways people are wearing shorts as they work outside in the fields, and they weren't required to go home to change before praying; even the shaliach tzibur could wear shorts.

On another occasion, I saw a friendly acquaintance wearing shorts in synagogue and mentioned that I'd been told it wasn't allowed, so he might want to check with his rabbi as to what to do. He responded by saying that it's short shorts that are prohibited, but his were knee-lengths and his rabbi said it was OK albeit not preferable in the first place.

Also: I thought about the "before the King" analogy and have the following issue with it. We're also "before the King" when we go anywhere, because He Is everywhere. So by that reasoning you couldn't wear shorts ever, and yet we find that there's an obligation to teach one's kids to swim, which obviously requires wearing shorts. If you were to respond by differentiating between a synagogue as being especially holy, that's a good point but I don't think it fully answers the issue. It's like someone who pointed out that men don't need to shower 3x/day just because they pray 3x/day.

Emotionally I'd like to be able to wear shorts in synagogue, intellectually I feel the holiness of the place bars that possibility. Don't test me for intellectual honesty :P

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Do you happen to remember the name of the book your rabbi consulted?  If so, adding that to your answer could help others research it further.  Thanks!

Comment: There is definitely a Halachic requirement to dress more "like in front of a king" when praying than normal.

Answer (score 0):

See Mishna Brurah 91:13 it seems that in very hot places it might be permitted.I believe later achronim discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting from Mishna Berura in 2:1 , Irrespective of davening You should never wear any clothing which does not  extend beyond your knees. The shape of your body also should not be discernible to the onlookers. Ideally all coverable parts of your body should be covered at all times not just davening.

Comment: This seems more like a comment as it doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: Aren't all parts of your body coverable except maybe your eyes?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull My eyes are often covered. Ever hear of sunglasses?

Answer (score 0):

there is a principle that things which can be derived from reason via "kal v'chomer" (major to minor logical inference) are obligatory even if they are not explicitly written in the torah.

The Talmud in Pesachim 75b discusses the prohibition of bringing coals which make too much smoke for the incense offering. There it says: "For that you don't need a verse, [to prohibit it] since before a flesh and blood king, one would not do this, how much more so before the King of kings, the Holy One blessed be He."

Hence, the torah does not write things which one can derive from reason even though they are obligatory. Just like it doesn't say anywhere that you can't daven while holding a cat.

So, to answer the question, under normal circumstances and for someone with some degree of intelligence as to Who he is praying to, it would seem to be forbidden by the above kal v'chomer.

Comment: Holding a cat is discussed in OC 97:5

Comment: I also wouldn't go meet the king without showering fairly recently. Is it forbidden to pray if I haven't showered that day?

Comment: depends how dirty you are. there's a big difference between going to meet a king without showering and going to meet a king wearing shorts. in the latter it may cost you your head.

Comment: What about in Zululand where short would be _overdressing_?

Answer (score 0):

The **Shulchan Aruch** ([Orach Chaim 91:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.91.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) seems to be of the opinion that one should **not** wear shorts while davening if that would seem inappropriate:

> לא יעמוד באפונדתו [טאסקא בלעז] ולא בראש מגולה ולא ברגלים מגולים אם דרך אנשי המקום שלא יעמדו לפני הגדולים אלא בבתי רגלים:
>
> A person should not stand with their money-belt ["taska" in the language of this country] on, or with an uncovered head or uncovered legs, if it is the practice of the people of that place not to stand in front of important people unless their legs are covered.

However, the **Mishnah Berurah** ([91:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.91.5?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.91.13&lang2=bi)) seems to grant a little leeway:

> מיהו אם הבגד ארוך שחופה את הרגלים או בארצות החמין מאוד שעומדי' שם ג"כ בפני גדולים יחף אין לחוש אפילו הבגדים קצרים ונראין הרגלים
>
> However if his clothing is long that it covers his legs, or in places of very warm weather and one would stand in front of important people even barefoot, one need not worry even if the clothes are short and one's legs can be seen

R' **[Ovadya Yosef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovadia_Yosef)** in **Yechaveh Da’at IV:8** (quoted in yeshiva.co articles [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/21166) and [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=3465)) also seems to allow wearing shorts in certain circumstances-- namely, in places and for people where shorts are commonplace (ex: kibbutzim, or kids during the summer), one is permitted to daven in shorts- though a person in shorts should not be chazzan.

Comment: How do you know רגלים means legs not feet? Mishna Berura explicitly contrasts it with יחף meaning barefoot.i don't think this is accurate.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm going off the aforementioned SA sefaria English translation of רגלים which they translate to mean legs

Comment: A better source for that key claim would improve this post imo