# Can a woman daven in a nightgown?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, women, clothing

Can a woman daven in a nightgown that she sleeps in and wears all day unless leaving the house? Or is this not allowed since by man it's not considered respectful to daven before Hashem in pajamas he slept in?

Comment: Why might you think that women are different from men in this regard?

Comment: Closely related - [Is there a halachik problem with wearing shorts while davening](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28555/501)

Answer (score -1):

Shemonah Esrei should not be davened in sleep clothes as it is not respectful to approach the King of all kings in such a manner.Regarding a nightgown without a belt or separation at the waist, "libo ro'eh es ha'erva" is less problematic by a woman as her erva is situated "below" instead of directly facing the heart as by a male.

Comment: Temp. downvote until you can edit in some sources to support this statement.

Comment: _separation at the waist_ is a **must** and may invalidate Tefila, whereas being dressed properly is not! Visit any hospital and see people praying _not properly dressed_.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Rabbi Everybodydoesit doesn't even have semicha.