# Can a Jewish man play football with shorts?

Tags: tznius-modesty, sport-athletics

Can a Jewish man wear shorts while playing football or must he wear tights under short for hides his skin? We know Jewish man should wear under knee. But football short above knee. So in football he must cover knee? Or he can play with shorts with no cover knee?

Comment: There is no reason in the world that a Jewish man cannot play football wearing shorts.

Comment: https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/tznius-for-men https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/3037 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/permissibility-of-wearing-shorts

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Bittul Torah?

Comment: @DoubleAA I was once in Gateshead shul and the (old) rov stood up and he said, "Summer is coming, and the *yetzer ha'ra* says, 'Go to the park and play cricket!''" So I think if that was the *yetzer ha'ra* today, we'd be doing pretty good.

Comment: "We know Jewish man should wear under knee". I don't know. Can you please clarify how that is known?